# Solve Toeplitz Matrix in underdetermined system

Tags: systems-of-equations, toeplitz-matrices

Let $A$ be an unknown matrix of the form:
$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} b & c_1 & c_2 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ c_2 & c_3 & c_4  \\ c_3 & c_4 & d\end{matrix} \right) $$

I have the known vectors
$$ x = \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3\end{matrix} \right) $$
and

$$ y = \left( \begin{matrix} y_1 \\ y_2\\ y_3\\y_4\end{matrix} \right) $$

The relation between these is
$Ax=y$

Is there a way to solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ knowing $x$ and $y$?

Any hints and help is appreciated!

Comment: Are $b$ and $d$ known in addition to $x$ and $y$? If so, then you just have $4$ linear equations for $4$ unknowns.

Comment: They are unknown but not needed

Comment: Yes, if you calculate $Ax=y$, you'll have four equations and four unknowns ($c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$) which you can solve for, either in terms of $b$ and $d$ in case those are unknown, or if they're known you'll have a numerical solution for $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$

Comment: It seems to me that this are four equations with six unknowns, of which I want to recover c1-c4